# what query or operator will help to find out the cumulative sum for array element in mongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

In mongoDb there is collection with following schema.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a497a00b0f3500c3b6fb7e6"),
  "student" : "A",
  "result" : [
             { test: "1",
               marks: 5
             },
             { test: "2",
               marks: 6
             },
             { test: "3",
               marks: 7
             },
             { test: "4",
               marks: 8
             },
            ]
}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a497a00b0f3500c3b6fb7h8"),
  "student" : "B",
  "result" : [
             { test: "a1",
               marks: 8
             },
             { test: "a2",
               marks: 9
             },
             { test: "a3",
               marks: 10
             },
             { test: "a4",
               marks: 12
             },
            ]
}
```

What i need to find out the cumulative sum of marks. I am using aggregation pipeline as there is also other operation have to perform on the data.

So If anyone can help me to figurine out the query or operator which help me to find out this.

E.g after query output should be this..

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a497a00b0f3500c3b6fb7e6"),
  "student" : "A",
  "result" : [
             { test: "1",
               marks: 5
             },
             { test: "2",
               marks: 11
             },
             { test: "3",
               marks: 18
             },
             { test: "4",
               marks: 26
             },
            ]
}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a497a00b0f3500c3b6fb7h8"),
  "student" : "B",
  "result" : [
             { test: "a1",
               marks: 8
             },
             { test: "a2",
               marks: 17
             },
             { test: "a3",
               marks: 27
             },
             { test: "a4",
               marks: 39
             },
            ]
}
```

Comment: not same, in output marks will have cumulative sum of previous marks.

Comment: why do you want to keep sum calculated in each stage in each variable. What are u trying to achieve? What you really need to find out is consolidated sum of marks(from all tests) for a student.

Comment: nope not a consolidate sum I have to find out the *test*  which is near to the predefined threshold value for marks(Progressive sum of marks), for each student

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: "$result",
            includeArrayIndex: "index"
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            student : { $first: "$student" },
            items: { $push: { test: "$result.test", index: "$index" } },
            values: { $push: "$result.marks" }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            result: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$items",
                    as: "item",
                    in: { test: "$$item.test", marks: { $sum: { $slice: [ "$values", { $add: [1, "$$item.index"] } ] } } }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            result: 1,
            student: 1
        }
    }
])
```

To calculate cumulative sum you need to have index assigned to each array item. To do that you can use `includeArrayIndex` option when using [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/). Then you can use that index for [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) to get subset of all elements based on index. So it is: one element array for index 0, two elements array for index 1 and so on. Having such variable length arrays you can use [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/index.html) to get cumulative sum.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var sum = (data) => {
    let total = 0;
    data.forEach((ele) => {
        total += ele.marks;
        ele.marks = total;
    });
    return data;
}


db.getCollection('Collection').find({}).forEach((data) => {
    data.marks = sum(data.marks);
    print(data);
})
```

Comment: hey @rahul, what if the same have to implement with the aggregation pipeline in mongodb

Answer (score 1):

There is no single operator, but you can use a combination of [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/), [$concatArrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/), [$mergeObjects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/), and [$add](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) to iterate the array and calculate cumulative sum yourself:

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
    { $project: {
        student: 1,
        marks: { $reduce: {
            input: "$marks",
            initialValue: [],
            in: { $let: {
                vars: { 
                    prev: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$value", { $subtract: [ { $size: "$$value" }, 1 ] } ] } 
                },
                in: { $concatArrays : [
                    "$$value", 
                    [ { $mergeObjects: [ 
                        "$$this",  
                        { marks: { $add: [ "$$this.marks",  { $ifNull: [  "$$prev.marks", 0 ] } ] } }
                    ] } ]
                ] }
            } }    
        } }
    } }
] )
```